# Passing a Context in a Constructor

Tags: android

in addition to the thread i started here

[Android: openFileOutput throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161519/android-openfileoutput-throws-nullpointerexception/23161567?noredirect=1#23161567)

Ok, so, at first i passed the context directly to the listToTextFile function and it worked fine.  After that i decided to pass the context as a parameter to the constructor of GenerateXml class like this:

```
    public GenerateXml(Context cntx){

        this.cntx = cntx;
    }
```

and i get the NullPointerException agian.
when debugging i can see that the assignment in the constructor has no effect and that "this.cntx" is really NULL.

Main Activity calls GenerateXml code:

```
private void parseAppListToXML(List<ApplicationInfo> packages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GenerateXml gXml = new GenerateXml(getApplicationContext());
        gXml.listToXml();
    }
```

LogCat shows NullPointerException - probably because this.cntx is Null:

```
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.example.tester.GenerateXml.<init>(GenerateXml.java:32)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.example.tester.MainActivity$1.parseAppListToXML(MainActivity.java:80)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.example.tester.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-20 11:20:17.580: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Class :

```
package com.example.tester;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
//import android.util.Xml;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class GenerateXml  {




//
// Attributes
//

protected Context cntx;

//Constructor gets caller Context

    public GenerateXml(Context cntx){

        this.cntx = cntx;
    }

final PackageManager pm = cntx.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);


public void listToXml() {

    // break List into array so late will print one line at a time to the file
    ListIterator<ApplicationInfo> iter = packages.listIterator();

    try { // catches IOException below

         FileOutputStream fOut =  cntx.openFileOutput("AppsList.XML",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
         osw.write("<INSTALLED_APPS_LIST>");
         while (iter.hasNext()) {
         // Write the string to the file

             osw.write("<APPLICATION>");
             osw.write("<PACKAGE>");
             osw.write(iter.next().toString());
             osw.write("</PACKAGE>");
            // osw.write(iter.);
             osw.write("</APPLICATION>");
             osw.write('\n');
         /* ensure that everything is
          * really written out and close */
         }
         osw.write("</INSTALLED_APPS_LIST>");

         osw.flush();
         osw.close();
     }catch (IOException e){
         //Log.e(TAG,"could not open file out stream", e); 
     }
}
}
```

???

Comment: please post logcat error, and post line that you pass context to `GenerateXml`

Comment: do you have `new  GenerateXml(ActivityName.this)` ??

Comment: `public class GenerateXml extends Activity{` is a Activity class. Why do you need a constructor which take context as a param. its wrong. laalto already answered your question in the link you posted

Comment: 1. added code and locat to post.    2.GenerateXml is not an Activity. (i changed it..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final PackageManager pm = cntx.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Member variables are initialized before the constructor is run and you only initialize `cntx` in constructor. Hence the NPE. Move these initializations to the constructor as well.